# How to customize Angular Material Form Field Component?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2

I just started using angular material, and I'm having issues getting the material components work the way I like.

I made a custom theme, but still there are some things that I don't like.

Here is my custom theme:

```
@include mat-core();
$DigitalSignageApp-primary: mat-palette($mat-pink);
$DigitalSignageApp-accent: mat-palette($mat-gray, A200, A100, A400);
$DigitalSignageApp-warn: mat-palette($mat-red);
$DigitalSignageApp-theme: mat-dark-theme($DigitalSignageApp-primary, $DigitalSignageApp-accent, $DigitalSignageApp-warn);

@include angular-material-theme($DigitalSignageApp-theme);
```

I wanted to use form field inside my project and the HTML for it is:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
          <input matInput placeholder="Email">
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
          <input matInput type="password" placeholder="Password">
        </mat-form-field>
```

This is how the layout looks like:
[image: before]

When I focus into the input field:
[image: after]

I want the text and border to have a white color (because it is more readable)

Comment: Use the Browser's inspector. That's your best friend to know what element you need to target from your CSS

Comment: I came here only after trying out the inspector

Comment: you should update custom css your component

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example using `[appearance]="'outline'"`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cvq3kq-g56tez

Feel free to extract the CSS rules to your theme, I'm using it in the styles.css file for demonstration purposes only. Basically you need to target:
`.mat-form-field-outline-end` and `.mat-form-field-outline-start` for the borders and for the placeholders you need to target `::placeholder` pseudo

Comment: This doesn't seem to work..the form label still remains red/pink color.
And the border after focusing on the input becomes red/pink